# I have installed a Plugin in Custom Theme(duplicate of RWD) but url is not loading and 500 http error has occurred

Tags: magento-1.9, zend-framework

I have installed store locator (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-map-store-locator.html) plugin in Magento 1.9.2.0 but the frontend is not responding.
Please give the solution.